# Send email with attachments in PHP?

Tags: php, email

How can I send emails with attachments with a PHP script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/).

Answer (score 3):

Use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

```
$message = new Swift_Message("My subject");

$message->attach(new Swift_Message_Part("Attached txt file"));
$message->attach(new Swift_Message_Attachment(new Swift_File("filename.txt"), "filename.txt", "text/txt"));

$swift->send($message, "email@host", "myemail@host");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at some of the PHP PEAR packages designed for sending emails. I know that some PHP programmers like reinventing the wheel, but take a look at the packages. They are easy to use and implement and you should have no problem finding help.

Here is a link:
http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

You may want to use the go-pear.php script to install the packages. It will make life a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want a php function, you can use this mail_file function:
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/10/sending-emails-with-attachment-and-html-with-php/

To send files you have to base64 encode the file and use the "header" parameter of the php mail function.

Hope this will help.