# How to send an email attachment using PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email with  attachments in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214646/send-email-with-attachments-in-php)

How can I send an email attachment using PHP without installing any thing and just using the mail() function?

Comment: There are a lot of questions answering that already, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214646/send-email-with-attachments-in-php). Please do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: @netcoder, I don't want to PHPMailer orr anything similar

Comment: Keep reading, and or use the search. There are dozens of questions providing multiple alternatives already. Posting duplicate questions is against SO rules, your question will probably be closed anyway. If you don't want PHPMailer, or Zend_Mail, or this, or that, at least specify it in the question.

Comment: @netcoder, I thought I did no need to get mad about it.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330626/how-can-i-send-an-email-with-attachments-from-a-php-form/1330629#1330629

Answer (score 0):

The zend framework has a nice class to do this.  It would require that you copy the framework to your server to access it.

http://framework.zend.com/

Comment: not really intrested in a frame work

Answer (score 0):

[PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) can use the native `mail()` function:

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$mail->SetFrom($fromAddress, 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo($replyToAddress, "First Last");
$mail->AddAddress($toAddress, "John Doe");
$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

// $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
// $mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: I really don't want to use PHPMailer?

Comment: @single Why not? It can be used as a wrapper for the `mail()` function, so you don't have to deal with headers and attachments. It's just a PHP class file. Have you tried it already?

Answer (score 0):

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));
```

Read [This Article](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use a multiplart/mixed MIME type and also base64_encode the attachment.

Check this link [Mail() Email Attachment](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The attachments are included in the body of the message. It is probably a good idea to be familiar with [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) and the MIME RFCs. The link that [Christopher Ickes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480329/how-to-send-an-email-attachment-using-php/4480359#4480359) and [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480329/how-to-send-an-email-attachment-using-php/4480354#4480354) gave will help with the implementation but the code glosses over the details that can help when debugging down the track.