# how to send attachment by email

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email with attachments in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214646/send-email-with-attachments-in-php)

I've many Joomla/Drupal sites running but I want to send a file attachment by email using php code on linux/unix command line, how can I do it?

When I use mail function in my shared hosting account, it's not send any mails.

Comment: How did you try to use the `mail` function exactly?

Comment: I've used single line mail(..) without any settings

Answer (score 0):

Are you having an issue sending any email, or just emails with attachments?

Some shared hosts aren't setup to be able to send email through PHP's built-in `mail()` function. In these cases, you'll need to explicitly connect to an SMTP server and send your mail that way. You should take a look into the [mail PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) or other solutions for connecting to an SMTP server.

The specific server you connect to should be in your shared servers documentation. If not, you'll need to contact their support people to have them provide this. In fact, it's probably a good idea to look into their support system/forums to ensure that this is the actual cause of the issue, and not some other coding issue.

Comment: How do my websites send email? Do the site use mail PEAR package?

Comment: @AgA I'm not sure what you're asking.